# What is the probability of getting an accident at least once by the end of the 10th day?

Tags: probability

The probability of not getting an accident at an intersection is 95% on any given day and this is independent every day. If today was accident free, find the probability that there is no accident during the next 4 days, but there is at least one by the end of the 10th day.

What I've done so far is define success as not getting an accident on a given day. It seems easier to simply subtract the probability of not having an accident in the next 9 days so $1-(.95)^9$ is what I have so far.

I suspect that I have a mistake in here somewhere-could anyone verify?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The probability that there is no accident in the next $4$ days is $(.95)^4$. The probability that there is at least one accident in the remaining 6 days is $1-(.95)^6$. Multiply them together and you get your answer $(1-(.95)^6)(.95)^4 = .216$. This is different from what you have because you assumed that you could subtract from 1 after you multiply but peMdaS (multiplication is before subtraction). Please let me know if you have any questions I would be more than happy to clarify what I have written :)

Comment: That makes more sense! Thank you :). You seem to have boiled the problem down to a bernoulli problem.

Comment: technically this is true, nice observation!